# How to set admin system configuration page to full width in Magento 2

Tags: magento, configuration, magento2

Is there a way to set group tabs use full width in system configuration pages like attribute section?

magento 2 system admin cofiguration:
[image: magento 2 system admin cofiguration]

Answer (score 0):

After a while I found this as a solution:

```
<item name="additionalClasses" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="admin__field-wide" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
</item>
```